# MSBuild combine files

Tags: msbuild

I'm trying to combine all javascript files in a project during the build process, but it just isn't working for me.  Here's what I have:

```
<Target Name="CombineJS">
  <CreateItem Include=".\**\*.js">
    <Output TaskParameter="Include" ItemName="jsFilesToCombine" />
  </CreateItem>

  <ReadLinesFromFile File="@(jsFilesToCombine)">
    <Output TaskParameter="Lines" ItemName="jsLines" />
  </ReadLinesFromFile>

  <WriteLinesToFile File="all.js" Lines="@(jsLines)" Overwrite="true" />
</Target>
```

MSBuild is throwing an error on the `ReadLinesFromFile` line saying there's an invalid value for the "File" parameter.  (No error when there's only one file to combine)

So, two questions:

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. Is there a better way to combine files within an MSBuild task?  I ask this question because I know that my current process removes all tabs and blank lines, which for me isn't that big of a deal, but still kind of annoying.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Change line 6 to:

```
<ReadLinesFromFile File="%(jsFilesToCombine.FullPath)">
```

The `@` operator is used when the input is [ItemGroup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/646dk05y.aspx) which is essentially a semicolon-delimited list of strings.

The `%` operator is for expanding ItemGroups into strings (properties).

Answer (score 2):

The `ReadLinesFromFileTask` you are using to read the files takes a single file as input to the `File` property ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164299.aspx)).  You can't use this task to read lines from multiple files at once.  You may however be able to use [batching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171473.aspx) to run the task several times for each file.